# How to add three.js autocomplete for Microsoft visual studio 2019?

Tags: three.js, autocomplete

I work with Microsoft visual studio 2019 and for the past month I've been working with the three.js library but it is very difficult that there is no autocomplete. So how to add three.js autocomplete for Microsoft visual studio 2019?